# Nginx/Passenger runs a Rails app owned by another user. How do i prevent doing "bundle install" for both users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger, rvm

---

### Environment

I used [passenger-install-nginx-module](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) to install Nginx/Passenger for user **nginxer**.

I uploaded a Rails project and owned it to user **projecter**.

Then i followed the [RVM integration with Passenger](http://beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/) manual and created the `.rvmrc` file, editing the paths so that they point to **projecter**'s .rvm. I also created the `config/setup_load_paths.rb` file and uncommented the two lines for Bundler 1.x.

I did `bunlde install` from user **projecter** and successfully performed migrations.

---

### Problem

But the project wouldn't start unless i do `bundle install` from the **nginxer** user:

```
no such file to load -- bundler/setup

Backtrace:
/home/nginxer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
```

I thought that Nginx/Passenger should run the app with the user who owns the project.

---

### Some environment info

Here's an `rvm gemset list` run by **nginxer** in the project folder:

```
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p290 (found in /home/redminer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)
   global
=> redmine
```

Here's an `rvm info` run by **nginxer** in the project folder:

```
$ rvm info

ruby-1.9.2-p290@redmine:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux li308-242 3.0.4-linode37 #1 SMP Mon Sep 12 12:00:58 EDT 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.8.3 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p290"
    date:         "2011-07-09"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@redmine"
    ruby:         "/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@redmine/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@redmine/bin:/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/projecter/.rvm/bin:/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nginxer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nginxer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/home/nginxer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/home/nginxer/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@redmine"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@redmine:/home/projecter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    IRBRC:        "/home/projecter/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "redmine"
```

---

### So the question is…

Is it normal that i have to do "bundle install" both for **nginxer** and for **projecter**?

If not, how do i make Nginx/Passenger use **projecter**'s gemset?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which user the passenger server runs as, are you doing that?

http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_user_lt_username_gt